# Where to obtain crisp new US bills in London?

Tags: money, exchange, cambodia, quarantine

I’m travelling to Cambodia and have to bring $2000 USD in cash to pay for the quarantine facility. Immigration are adamant that I have to bring brand new crisp US currency (no tears, marks, creases etc). This has been corroborated by embassy officials and numerous experiences of people on visa forums (and my friends who have been through the process). Yes it says I can pay by card, but numerous people report the card machine being faulty… and then being turned away because they hadn’t had a cash alternative. Anyway I’m not taking any chances.

I’ve asked many money changers here in London and they can’t guarantee that they can do that for me. Where can I obtain these new notes - any leads appreciated

Comment: https://media.heartlandtv.com/images/Scam+Alert5.jpg

Comment: @chx Why? When travelling to Cambodia, you do actually at the moment have to deposit 2000 USD at a Cambodian bank for any potential charges for health service.

Comment: The [official page](https://www.mfaic.gov.kh/covid-19) repeatedly states the requirement for the 2000 USD deposit, but I don't see any reference to "brand new crisp US currency (no tears, marks, creases etc)". They also state that the deposit can be make using a credit card: "_Then they must make a deposit (by cash or credit card) of 2,000USD (two thousand US dollars)
with a designated commercial bank at point of entry_". What's the source for that requirement?

Comment: @jcaron Likely the bank he is intending to deposit the money with. I mean, it is very common in Asia and Africa that banks and money changers only want pristine dollar bills, mainly because of how easy they are to forge and how difficult it is to detect good counterfeits. I don't understand why that rings any warning bells for you.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I understand they wouldn't want torn or marked bills, but to the point they should be "brand new" and "crisp" that seems a bit too much. Also most bills have good security features, especially the larger denominations. But it's been a long time since I've last deposited any physical currency in a bank...

Comment: @jcaron It might be too much for you, but that is a common custom in many countries, dating back to older bill series. Even if newer series, at least the higher denominations, have some up-to-date security features, US dollar bills are still relatively easy to counterfeit and they are at a very high rate. To quote this page: "Cambodia likes its US Dollars crisp and clean, and they’ll even reject your payments if they don’t like the looks of your bills." - https://peopleplacesandthoughts.com/home/2019/8/13/cambodias-curious-use-of-the-us-dollar

Comment: @jcaron yeah they do accept card but it is according to the whims of whether the machine works on that particular day. Unfortunately it’s very much not a scam, corroborated by Cambodian embassy officials and my friends and family who have gone through the process also had to do the same. On visa forums many people have attested to being turned back to their last port because they couldn’t come up with quality notes. I think it has to do with the money counting facilities they have at their airport. The same goes for Turkmenistan, for eg, as stated in official gov.uk guidance

Comment: Does your bank supports ordering of travel money, with a procedure (e.g. a phone call) that enables staff to add an internal note that you require crisp new banknotes? As @Tor-EinarJarnbjo noted, there are many countries where people _expects_ new banknotes from the counter, and banks with an international presence are likely to be able to accommodate that.

Comment: Unless you're willing (and able) to do a side trip to the US (and even then I'm not sure there is a way to guarantee crisp new bills), I think the only option for you is to: a) try to pay with a credit card if possible, b) ask for $100 notes, which probably circulate less and should be less damaged, c) reject any notes that don't look perfect when you get them and d) have more cash than requested so if some bills are rejected you have others to replace them with. I have no idea if nowadays money changers have plenty of USD available on demand or if you have to request them in advance?

Comment: I used to get them from my bank in Hong Kong, they seemed to stock new US$100 bills for trips like that. A bank in Singapore might be a good bet as well.

Comment: They might not be able to promise you shiny new notes at some indefinite date in the future, but can you go and ask for $2000 of their crispest, newest dollars right now? And if they say they don't have any that you like the look of, go somewhere else?

Comment: I can verify the requirement for crisp, new $100 bills, at least in Siem Riep.  Even at the store owned by our tour guide's wife they rejected some of our cash.  I tried persuading her, but she wouldn't budge.

Comment: If TV is a reliable guide, money laundering of cash starts with *actual* landering. Have you got an iron?

Comment: Won't guarantee brand new crisp notes but try ATMs in London? https://www.link.co.uk/consumers/locator Select USD as currency in the filter. You can just try withdrawing single note at first to test it out. Obviously make sure your bank doesn't charge fees when withdrawing foreign currency (Starling Bank is the best for this but there are other options too).

Comment: @djr that might work best at a post office with currency exchange, rather than a bank - many, probably most, bank branches in the UK get their foreign currency delivered to order.  Branches in the centre of major cities might be better, and you'll also find bureaux de change.

Comment: Try the Iranian embassy. They've connections with the Iranian government who print a lot of US dollars apparently...

Comment: Won't they accept euros? Normally euro banknotes are safer against counterfeiting.

Comment: @Movingsheen Have you tried asking in a bank? Banks could have better access to new banknotes than money changers...

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/57757/36213 may be interesting.

Answer (score -5):

In my experience, banks will sell foreign currency, especially when arranged in advance. If you have an account with a major bank in London, contact them to ask about buying US dollars, and ask if they can get new bills for you.

Comment: And how sure are you to get new crisp notes? I think that is unlikely, they will just hand out what they have.

Comment: As I wrote, one can ask the bank about obtaining new bills. Especially in a major banking center such as London, many banks have U.S. affiliates as well as buy and sell foreign currency themselves. Banks in the U.S., and some overseas banks, buy currency from the U.S. Treasury. Within the U.S., banks obtain newly-minted bills and introduce them into circulation. Overseas banks, especially in a major banking center, may do the same and/or have their U.S. partner do it.

Comment: In answers to other questions on this site, and comments, I have read that most banks do not give out new crisp notes even when you ask for those. In many cases they are not even giving out the value of the notes you request, giving a mix of $20, $50 and $100 rather than only the one you asked for.

Comment: jetset nit: actually, currency distribution in US is handled by the [Federal Reserve Bank System](https://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/coin_about.htm) which is legally separate from the Treasury Department. Notes are _printed_ by the BEP (in Treasury), and [_backed by_ the government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve_Note) but actually _issued_ by FRB. In contrast coins are struck _and issued_ by the Mint (also in Treasury) and sold at face value to FRB for distribution. But none of that affects dealing with retail customers by banks.

Comment: @Willeke, that may be the case for casual retail bank transactions, such as withdrawing $100 from one's account. But the topic here is purchasing U.S. currency while overseas.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, good points, thank you for the clarification.